# Change permissions of mounted subfolders

Tags: virtualbox, mount, shared-directory

I'm using windows 7 as host and debian 6 in a VirtualBox VM. The guest additions are installed to share a folder provided by the host system.
In debian runs a webserver. So far everything is good.
But it's required to change the permissions on subfolders too. The shared folder is mounted with

```
mount -t vboxsf -o permissions,umask=0000,uid=33,gid=33 webdev /var/www
```

Is there any way to realize this?
The alternative is a samba share on the guest system, but that would be slow.